# Can't seem to pass variable from AS3 to Javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

This code does not work. (Passing variable from AS3 to Javascript)

AS3 (declare variable and pass to Javascript)

```
var newHeight:Number = new Nubmer();
newHeight = 2;

goHeight();

function goHeight():void{
if (ExternalInterface.available){
ExternalInterface.call("funYa1()", newHeight);
}

}
```

In the HTML docment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function funYa1(nH) {       
alert("newHeight   " + nH);
}           

</script>
```

The alert says nH is undefined. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in the first line

```
var newHeight:Number = new Nubmer();
```

should be

```
var newHeight:Number = new Number();
```

Are you using swfObject to embed swf?
If yes, try adding:

```
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
```

Also you could try passing a hard-coded string instead of newHeight, to see if it is a problem with the variable:

```
ExternalInterface.call("funYa1()", "test");
```

Here is a nice article about as3 and javascript communication:

http://circlecube.com/2010/12/actionscript-as3-javascript-call-flash-to-and-from-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

The alert says `nH` is undefined because you have braces in the call. In this case argument is not passed. Substitute the row

```
ExternalInterface.call("funYa1()", newHeight);
```

with

```
ExternalInterface.call("funYa1", newHeight);
```

and argument should be delivered to Javascript.